# In Android, how do I test an activity that depends on the result of another activity?

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

In a very basic example, I have my first activity (activity1) which the user enters in their username and password. If they are correct, a rnd-token is generated from a server and passed into activity2.

Activity2 does something that is based on the token generated in activity1.

Im using Espresso to fill in the user credentials and press the button in activity1. Is there a way I can start a AndroidTest from the completion of activity1Test? Is there a way I can automate the entire life-cycle of my app?

Thanks!

Comment: You likely want to use [Espresso-Intents](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/intents#stubbing). Rather than testing the Activity2 does the right thing, you just test that Activity1 sends the correct intent to Activity2, and then stub an `ActivityResult` to test how Activity1 responds to different results from Activity2. Then, you can write separate tests for Activity2 that verify it sends the correct ActivityResult based on the Intent you start it with.

Answer (score 0):

I think separation of concerns is probably a better approach. Use the LiveData class and have the activities observe the data?